# Count occurrences of distinct values using Laravel Query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can I write the following in Laravel Query builder?

```
SELECT name,COUNT(*) as count FROM tablename GROUP BY name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Example DB:

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          Mike
3          Paul
4          Mike
5          Mike
6          John
7          Mark
```

Expected Result:

```
name       count
-----      -----
Mike       3
Mark       2
Paul       1
John       1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DB::table('table')
  ->selectRaw('name, COUNT(*) as count')
  ->groupBy('name')
  ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
  ->get();
```